# jQuery force dynamic event to bind first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm binding events on the document element to make them dynamic.

The problem is that these events execute AFTER events binded directly on the elements.

I have code that binds an element to execute first, but it doesn't work with dynamic content. Here is the code I would use for non dynamic content :

```
bindFirst: function (name, fn) {
        var elem, handlers, i, _len;
        this.bind(name, fn);
        for (i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++) {
            elem = this[i];
            handlers = jQuery._data(elem).events[name.split('.')[0]];
            handlers.unshift(handlers.pop());
        }
    }
```

This function is under .fn.extend.

As I said earlier, I want to be able to do the same, for for dynamic content bound on the document variable. Eg...

```
$(document).on("click", "div", function(){});
```

I want this to execute AFTER the code directly above :

```
$("div").on("click", function(){});
```

Comment: It should....... event delegation should happen after the events bound to the element directly. If you want event delegation to happen first, than that is not going to happen.

Comment: @epascarello My bad, I edited the post. I want the below code to execute AFTER the above code.

Comment: @epascarello I want to force the dynamic event to execute on all divs first.

Comment: It can not happen. Click happens on the child and than travels up the DOM to the document. The document is the last thing t get the click.

Comment: @epascarello Hmm. This is a problem. I need to find a way.

Comment: It is not possible, you need to figure out something diferent.

Answer (score 0):

Like @epascarello wrote in the comment:

*this is not possible, you need to figure out something different.*

A workaround must be thought around the logic of your code.  In any case I propose you a "let me say" bad code just to create the evidence of what should happen in order to revert event bubling.

Use the [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method in order to add parameters and use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in order to avoid an infinite loop.

Test in the delegated event if the current element has the click event handler and so trigger again the event.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(document.body).append($('<div/>', {text: 'CLICK ME: NEW DIV'}));
});

$("div").on("click", function(e, fromInner){
    // revert event bubling....
    if (fromInner == undefined) {
        return;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    //normal code.........
    console.log('Normal click event');
});

$(document).on("click", "div", function(e) {
  // revert event bubling....
  if ($._data(this).events != undefined && $._data(this).events[e.type] != undefined) {
      $(this).trigger('click', ['fromInner']);
  }
  console.log('Delegated Click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="btn">Add new DIV</button>
<div>CLICK ME</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with jQuery event delegation, it just uses event bubbling, which works from the target element out to the containers. But the plain Javascript `addEventListener()` method also supports event *capture*, which goes the other direction. The optional third argument can be used to enable capture mode for an event listener. See [Event Bubbling and Capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

So I think you should be able to write:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function() {...}, true);
```